# Repeat values in SQL query

Tags: sql-server

I have data in a table that looks like this

```
TeacherNo  TeacherName
1          Smith
2          Doe
```

I need to run a query that will produce output that looks something like this. Note the ProductID values below would just be hardcoded values in my script.

```
TeacherNo  TeacherName  ProductID
1          Smith        ABC
1          Smith        DEF
1          Smith        GHI
2          Doe          ABC
2          Doe          DEF
2          Doe          GHI
```

I know I could do it by repeating my sql statement and doing UNION ALL, however I didn't want to repeat my code so many times (in reality these may be repeated up to 6 times each)

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM   YOURTABLE
       CROSS JOIN (VALUES ('ABC'),
                          ('DEF'),
                          ('GHI')) tc(product_id)
```

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/243e5/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below

```
   Create table #dummytbl(ProductId nvarchar(50));
   INSERT INTO #dummytbl VALUES ('ABC');
   INSERT INTO #dummytbl VALUES ('DEF');
   INSERT INTO #dummytbl VALUES ('GHI');
   select i.TeacherNo, i.TeacherName, d.ProductId  from Teacher i
          inner join #dummytbl
          order by i.TeacherNo;
```

Comment: I believe you need a `ON` condition where **RHS = LHS** (ie) `1=1` or `'A' = 'A'`